# Determine from AWTEvent if it is a Mouse_Exited event

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, glasspane

In the software we are writing we employ a GlassPane at times to prevent the user from interacting with the program whilst it is busy, this is having the unintended side effect that the roll-over of certain buttons is being set but not removed.

Roll-over set, glass pane activated, glass-pane consumes mouse_exit event.

The GlassPane is registered as:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(this, 
                AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK
                | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK 
                | AWTEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL_EVENT_MASK );
```

as we found that we needed to catch mouse motion and mouse wheel events too.

```
public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {
                ((KeyEvent)event).consume();
            } else if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                ((MouseEvent) event).consume();
            }
}
```

Is there anyway of finding out at the above point in the code if the event comes from a Mouse_Exit event?

Comment: Check `MouseEvent#getID` and compare to it `MouseEvent. MOUSE_EXITED`

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I needed to do and it's solved the problem nicely

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [Disabled Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) approach. It add listeners to the GlassPane to intercept the events.

The code doesn't currently use a MouseWheelListener so you may need to add that.